# Aplicar código rmarkdown según el formato de salida knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown

Es posible conocer el formato de salida knitr para utilizar un código rmarkdown según la misma. En un documento rmarkdown necesitaría aplicar un código u otro según el formato de salida que haya elegido con knitr, es decir, sería algo así:

```
if (formato salida knitr es .pdf)
{...}
else
{...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")`:

````
```{r}

if (knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") == "html") {
  print("Estamos generando un HTMl")
} else {
  if (knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") == "latex") {
    print("Estamos generando un latex/PDF")
    } else {
      if (knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") == "docx") {
        print("Estamos generando un Word")
      }
    }
}
```
````

Esto debería funcionar, cada vez que hagas click en el botón de `knit` de Rstudio, pero también si generas el documento desde cualquier script que invoque a  `rmarkdown::render()`, lo que sí, este "chunk" no va a funcionar cuando lo ejecutas individualmente por que ciertamente no va a estar configurada la variable `rmarkdown.pandoc.to`, podrías eventualmente manejar un función que en este caso, retorne una tipo por defecto:

```
output_format <- function(default="html") {
  f <- knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
  if (length(f) == 0)
    return(default)
  else
    return(f)
}
```